How to determine the occurrence of 4 points in one plane in Euclidean geometry
Today I was trying to compile the basic laws of Euclidean geometry, and I found that I was missing something basic.
I want to determine whether 4 points fall in one plane or not
Note that my question is related to Euclidean geometry so please I don't want answers like we calculate the equation of the plane and check that the coordinates of the point satisfy the equation, forget something called a coordinate system
Suppose you know the six lengths between the points and each other and I want a direct law to apply it and check this
Initial attempt:
We are told by Heron's formula for the area of a triangle that if a triangle has side lengths $a,b,c$ and $p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ its area $S$ then:
$S=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$
We can calculate the areas of the four triangles this way, and then if the area of the larger triangle is equal to the sum of the areas of the remaining three triangles, this means that the points are in one plane.
If the above is unfulfilled and there is no pair of triangles whose total area is equal to the sum of the areas of the other pair, this means that the points do not fall in one plane
My main problem is with the case where there is a pair of triangles whose area sums up to the sum of the areas of the other pair of triangles.
I also wish if there was a simpler technique to deal with the problem using Euclidean geometry I would be grateful, thank you

One can use a similar formula for volume , as in wikipedia, and check if the volume is $0$. But it's not pretty.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140214/volume-of-tetrahedron-given-6-sides   and  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html

Let $P_1, \ldots, P_4$ be your points and $d_{ij}$ the distance from $P_i$ to $P_j$.  The Cayley-Menger determinant of your points is the determinant $D$ of the $5 \times 5$ matrix
$$ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\cr
            1 & 0 & d_{12}^2 & d_{13}^2 & d_{14}^2\cr
            1 & d_{12}^2 & 0 & d_{23}^2 & d_{24}^2\cr
            1 & d_{13}^2 & d_{23}^2 & 0 & d_{34}^2 \cr
            1 & d_{14}^2 & d_{24}^2 & d_{34}^2 & 0\cr} $$
The volume $V$ of the convex hull of $P_1, \ldots, P_4$ satisfies
$$ V^2 = \frac{D}{288} $$
In particular, the four points are coplanar if and only if $D = 0$.

This is a lovely solution!

I think I've found the idea I'm looking for, but I still need to do the calculations.

Suppose all the points lie in one plane
Data: You know the values of lengths: $\bar{AB},\bar{BC},\bar{CA},\bar{R_{1}},\bar{R_{2}}$
also you know that $R_{1}∩R_{2}=(D_{1},D_{2})$.
Asks: Calculate the two lengths:
$\bar{AD_{1}},\bar{AD_{2}}$
Now if you can calculate the equation and make $\bar{BD}=\bar{R_{1}}$ and $\bar{CD}=\bar{R_{2}}$
Then check if $\bar{AD}=\bar{AD_{1}}$ or
$\bar{AD}=\bar{AD_{2}}$
This will determine if the $D$ falls into the same Plane as points $A,B,C$ or not.
This means that now all we need is:
$f(\bar{AB},\bar{BC},\bar{CA},\bar{R_{1}},\bar{R_{2}})=(\bar{AD_{1}} ,\bar{AD_{2}})$
